# Glidepath difference

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures

I recently flew an RNAV/LPV instrument approach in IMC.  Although out of the clouds by then, I was watching my vertical guidance on my NAV (which was at center) and noticed I was below glideslope for the visual PAPI.  Are my instruments wrong or does LPV and Visual Glide Slop Indicator (VGSI) really have a difference in glide path?

Comment: Which approach?  (some specifically mention it if they aren't coincident.)

Comment: It may also help to specify the airport and the type you were flying. PAPI lights are often calibrated for the sort of aircraft common at an airfield

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon for the glide path for an instrument approach to differ from the visual glideslope.  This is generally noted on the approach plate.

You can see this in the example below where just above the profile view there is a note stating:  “VGSI and RNAV glide path not coincident. (VGSI angle 3.00/TCH 55)”.

[image]